vue router installations to an existing Vue.js project returning error
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: cutify-web-app@0.1.0
npm error Found: vue@2.7.16
npm error node_modules/vue
npm error   vue@"^2.6.14" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.4.0
npm error node_modules/vue-router
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Phanz\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-02T15_22_07_936Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Phanz\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-07-02T15_22_07_936Z-debug-0.log
i tried to install vue router for my vue project and it returned this error

You're trying to use Vue Router 4.4.0 with Vue 2. Vue Router 4.4.0 is only compatible with Vue 3.
You either need to upgrade to Vue 3, or downgrade Vue router to Vue router 3. Take a look at the docs for more information.
